# React-native android: gradle clean fails

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm using react native to develop an android app. When I run the command
`./gradlew clean`

I get these errors:

```
> Task :app:clean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory '/Users/XXXXXX/APPNAME/android/app/build'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
```

And the directories it points to are all variations on this: `android/app/build/intermediates/merged_res_blame_folder/debug/out/*`

Some things I've tried:

- changing ownership of the files/folders
- ending all java processes from Activity Monitor
- ending Daemons with `./gradlew --stop`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. For what it's worth I've followed all the steps outlined in https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by manually deleting the `/android/app/build` folder and rerunning `./gradlew clean`. For some reason I could not delete it from the command line so I had to use the file explorer gui.